# Sanitizing scripts with bypassSecurityTrustStyle in Angular

Tags: angular

I need to strip any `script` tags from a string, but keeping `style`.

If I sanitize the `style` of this string:

```
getSanitized(s: string) {
    const safeStyle: any = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(s);
    return safeStyle.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
}

const s = '<span style="font-size:18px;color:blue">This is a title</span>';
console.log(this.getSanitized(s));
```

I get the same string, as it only contains styles, and that seems to work fine.

But if the string contains a `script`, such as

```
const s = `<script>alert(1);</script>  
           <span onclick="javascript:alert(2);" 
                 style="font-size:18px;color:blue">This is a title</span>';`
console.log(this.getSanitized(s));
```

The `script` tag and the `onclick` attribute are not eliminated from the string. Why is it not eliminated if I'm sanitizing at the `style` level?

Comment: **bypass** means that an object is created that will allow the template to render the contents and bypass the sanitizer. It does not modify anything. You should only use it with **trusted** data. This does not sound like you trust the data.

Comment: I let users customize the Highcharts tooltip, that's HTML markup they can enter, but I need to allow only styles and filter any scripts. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a tough XSS question, because there are many attack vectors in CSS. People can get JavaScript to run if you give them access to run CSS on a page.

Comment: https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2013/10/30/executing-javascript-inside-css-another-reason-to-whitelist-and-encode-user-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular Sanitizer does not modify the passed HTML content. It does not extract anything from it. You need to do this manually. For example, you can parse the passed HTML content, remove unnecessary code from it and serialize it to a string again.

I know the [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) package that can build an AST from HTML. You can use it to parse your HTML. To serialize an AST to a string, you can use the [dom-serializer](https://github.com/cheeriojs/dom-serializer) package.

Thus, using these packages or similar, your `getSanitized` function logic may follow:

```
async getSanitized(s: string): Promise<string> {
  // 1. make an AST from HTML in a string format
  const dom = await this.getAST(s);
  // 2. remove unwanted nodes from the AST
  const filteredDOM = this.filterJS(dom);
  // 3. serialize the AST back to a string
  const result: string = serializer(filteredDOM);
  return result;
}
```

The `getAST` function just uses the `htmlparser2` API to get an AST from a string:

```
getAST(s: string): Promise<DomElement[]> {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const parser = new Parser(
      new DomHandler((err, dom) => {
        if (err) {
          rej(err);
        } else {
          res(dom);
        }
      })
    );
    parser.write(s);
    parser.end();
  });
}
```

The `filterJS` function removes unnecessary nodes. There is an online visualizer for an AST `htmlparser2` generates: https://astexplorer.net/. You can easily see what conditions you need to use to filter nodes. The `filterJS` function may be implemented as:

```
filterJS(dom: DomElement[]): DomElement[] {
  return dom.reduce((acc, node) => {
    if (node.type === 'tag') {
      node.attribs = this.filterAttribs(node.attribs);
      node.children = this.filterJS(node.children);
    }
    if (node.type !== 'script') {
      acc.push(node);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

In short, it removes `script` tags and calls the `filterAttribs` function to remove JavaScript from event handlers. The `filterAttribs` function may be:

```
filterAttribs(attribs: { [s: string]: string }) {
  return Object.entries(attribs).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (!key.startsWith('on')) {
      acc[key] = value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Basically, it removes attributes starting from 'on', i.e. event handlers.

The `serializer` function is a call to the `dom-serializer` library.

Don't forget to import `htmlparser2` and `dom-serializer`:

```
import { DomHandler, Parser, DomElement } from 'htmlparser2';
import serializer from 'dom-serializer';
```

For better TypeScript experience, the `htmlparser2` library provides type definitions by using the [@types/htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/htmlparser2) package.

You can find a working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-busvys.